# Giving path with blank spaces  to iis express fails

Tags: iis-express

When I run IISExpress from command line, a path like `c:\site` works fine.

But if I change it to:

```
H:\Users\Username\Document\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestIISExpress\TestIISExpress\bin\Debug\site
```

it fails i.e. it gives general error saying command line parameters switch needs - ,/ etc etc.

Anybody faced same issue? Does it works on yours?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would believe if you have a path with spaces in it, you'd have to put it into double quotes:

```
"H:\Users\Username\Document\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\TestIISExpress\TestIISExpress\bin\Debug\site"
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks bro,that worked :)..and +1 too for formatting my post.Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I have found, using IIS Express 8.0, that in order to provide a `path` switch that includes spaces the path must be preceded by a double quote, but there should be no terminating double quote, for instance:

```
"%ProgramFiles%\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" -path:"c:\my site\
```

I have no explanation for this behaviour, I have found no documentation concerning this issue, and I do not know what program versions this applies to.